# knn3 in caret package, train() function - R

Tags: r, data-modeling, r-caret, knn

I'm trying to run a knn with `train()` function with the `knn3` method:

```
model_KNN <- train(Y ~ ., training, method = "knn3", trControl = trainControl(
method = "cv", number = 10, verboseIter = TRUE)
```

However, it gives me the next error:

```
Error: Model knn3 is not in caret's built-in library
```

And I have installed caret package like this (and it works with my other functions too):

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
```

And also you can see the method `knn3` in `train()` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.18/topics/train

And it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Voting to close. Originally, I thought it was because knn3 was not in caret but it was apparently at one time anyway. I'm leaving the close vote because there is no reproducible example and no description of versions of R, caret, or OS. SO's interface does not allow one to amend the reason for closure. I'll withdraw the vote if the question is [edit]-ed to remedy its deficiencies. (And @Chris; why haven't you accepted any answers to your earlier questions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking at an older version of the package documentation (4.18) but are most likely running the [latest version (6.0-79)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-79/topics/train).

It appears that `knn3` may have been renamed to `knn` at some point, although I cannot find evidence of that other than the fact that `knn3` is missing and replaced with `knn`.

You can run `names(getModelInfo())` for a list of the different arguments available for the `model` parameter. There is also a list of models found [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html).